# Java JFXPanel: eventHandler returning button held instead of button pressed

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, jfoenix

I am trying to setup an event handler for a click, to added on a scene within a JFXPanel:

```java
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> System.out.println("Button pressed: " + event.getButton().name()));
```

Strangely enough, if I hold the primary button and click the secondary or middle button, the button returned by `event.getButton()` is the primary button, not the button that triggered the click.

So for example if I hold the primary button down and click on the middle button, the code above will have the console print `Button pressed: PRIMARY`.

I tried in a purely JavaFX application, and there `getButton()` always returns the button pressed; the issue is thus with the JFXPanel.

Is there an explanation, or workaround for this strange behavior?

Here is a complete example:

```java
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Test::initAndShowGUI); }

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // Setup the JFXPanel inside a JPanel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Platform.runLater(() -> initFX(fxPanel));
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Group  root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        // The event handler that incorrectly returns the button held instead of the one pressed
        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> System.out.println("Button pressed: " + event.getButton().name()));

        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }
}
```

Run the code above and click the secondary button while holding down the primary to get the message "Button pressed: PRIMARY" instead of "Button pressed: SECONDARY".

I tested it out and the behavior is present in both Java 10 and Java 14.It is also present for `MOUSE_RELEASED` and `MOUSE_CLICKED`.

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a current bug in Java.

The source of the bug is the function `mouseButtonToEmbedMouseButton` in class `SwingEvents` of package `com.sun.javafx.embed.swing`.

The function is supposed to convert a Swing mouse button into a JavaFX mouse button.

As an illustration, the following code

```java
SwingEvents.mouseButtonToEmbedMouseButton(intButton, MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK)
```

will always return `1`, no matter what value `intButton` takes.

Looking at the source code for `mouseButtonToEmbedMouseButton`, the problem is the if statement

```java
if ((extModifiers & MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) != 0){
    abstractButton = AbstractEvents.MOUSEEVENT_PRIMARY_BUTTON;}
```

where `extModifiers` is the second argument of the function. So if `extModifiers` is `MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK`, the `abstractButton` (what is returned) will always be set to 1.